# ASP.NET core how could i get my websites url/hostname when the program starts up

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to get my site's host name so I can change the directory of the JSON file that I am adding to my project. I just have no clue how I can collect the URL.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("wwwroot/sites/"environment"/"environment".json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddLog4Net();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url in the following ways.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(null);
        host.Start();
        var serverAddress = host.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
        foreach (var address in serverAddress)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(address);
            var port = uri.Port;

            Console.WriteLine($"Bound to port: {port}");
        }
        host.WaitForShutdown();
    }

    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the server features line"does NOT contain def for server features" I have to use IWebHostBuilder so I don't know I workaround for this.